# How to set position absolute on the parent absolute element?

Tags: html, css

Need help on achieving following UI. Displaying inner child element out/top of the parent element which is having position absolute. Is this achievable using CSS? 

**Note**:
I can't remove overflow property from the css.. (.absolute1) block having lot of data at least i have to give overflow-y:scroll;
[image]

This is what I have tried [JSFIddle](https://jsfiddle.net/adtp1592/)

```css
div.relative {
  position:relative;
  border:3px solid #73AD21;
  height:350px;
  width:550px;
  z-index:111;
}

.absolute1 {
  position:absolute;
  border:2px solid skyblue;
  width:200px;
  height:150px;
  z-index:555;
  overflow:auto;
}

.absolute2 {
  box-shadow:2px 2px 2px 2px #CCC;
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
  position:absolute;
  right:0;
  top:0;
  z-index:999;
  background:yellow;
  margin-right:-25px;
}
```

```html
<div class="relative">
  Test data Test Data Test Data
  <div class="absolute1">
    SomedataT Data Test Data Test data Test Data Test DataTest data Test Data 
    <div class="absolute2">
      top 2
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You've already set `position: absolute` on the containing parent element `.absolute1` and if you remove the `overflow: auto` rule you have declared on this element as well you end up with the result you demonstrate in the provided image. **See:** https://jsfiddle.net/adtp1592/2/

Comment: @JustuseFlex I can't remove overflow property from the css.. (.absolute1) block having lot of data at least I have to give overflow-y: auto;

Comment: Probably worth mentioning that in your question, because people think that's the right answer.

Comment: This is what you need to do: https://jsfiddle.net/adtp1592/4/ If this effectively addresses your problem, let me know and I'll add as an answer so that you can mark it as correct and close the question officially.

Comment: @JustuseFlex Perfect thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Remove `overflow:auto` in `.absolute1` class. and wrap content of `absolute1` in div and give it to `overflow:auto`.

```css
div.relative {
  position: relative;
  border: 3px solid #73AD21;
  height:350px;
  width:550px;
  z-index:111;
  padding: 15px;
}
.absolute1 {
  position:absolute;
  border:2px solid skyblue;
  width:200px;
  height:150px;
  z-index:555;  
}
.absolute1_desc{
  overflow:auto;
}
.absolute2 {
  box-shadow:2px 2px 2px 2px #CCC;
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
  position:absolute;
  right:0;
  top:0;
  z-index:999;
  background:yellow;
  margin-right:-25px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>    
  <div class="relative">
  Test data Test Data Test Data
    <div class="absolute1">
        <div class="absolute1_desc">SomedataT Data Test Data Test data Test Data Test DataTest data Test Data </div>
        <div class="absolute2">
        top 2
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I can't remove overflow property from the css..  (.absolute1) block having lot of data at least i have to give overflow-y:scroll;

Comment: Ok now please check.

Answer (score 1):

Keep content in `absolute1` in another `div` called `absolute3` with styles given and remove `border` to `absolut1` and `margin-right:-25px` to `absolut2`

```css
div.relative {
  position:relative;
  border:3px solid #73AD21;
  height:350px;
  width:550px;
  z-index:111;
}

.absolute1 {
  position:absolute;
  padding-right:25px;
  width:200px;
  height:150px;
  z-index:555;
  overflow:auto;
}

.absolute3 {
  position:absolute;
  right:25px;
  top:0;
  bottom:0;
  border:2px solid skyblue;
}

.absolute2 {
  box-shadow:2px 2px 2px 2px #CCC;
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
  position:absolute;
  right:0;
  top:0;
  z-index:999;
  background:yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="relative">
  Test data Test Data Test Data
  <div class="absolute1">
  <div class="absolute3">
    SomedataT Data Test Data Test data Test Data Test DataTest data Test Data 
    </div>
    <div class="absolute2">
      top 2
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to nest another element within `.absolute1` and declare your `overflow` rules to this nested element instead, as demonstrated in the embedded code snippet below:

```
/* Additional */
.absolute1 .text-wrapper {
  overflow: auto;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```css
div.relative {
    position: relative;
    border: 3px solid #73AD21;
    height:350px;
    width:550px;
    z-index:111;
}
.absolute1 {
position:absolute;
border:2px solid skyblue;
width:200px;
height:150px;
z-index:555;
}

/* Additional */
.absolute1 .text-wrapper {
  overflow: auto;
  height: 100%;
}

.absolute2 {
box-shadow:2px 2px 2px 2px #CCC;
width:50px;
height:50px;
position:absolute;
right:0;
top:0;
z-index:999;
background:yellow;
margin-right:-25px;
}
```

```html
<div class="relative">
layer 1
  <div class="absolute1">
  <div class="text-wrapper">
    Layer 2 Layer 2   Layer 2 Layer 2   Layer 2 Layer 2Layer 2 Layer 2   Layer 2 Layer 2   Layer 2 Layer 2Layer 2 Layer 2   Layer 2 Layer 2   Layer 2 Layer 2Layer 2 Layer 2   Layer 2 Layer 2   Layer 2 Layer 2Layer 2 Layer 2   Layer 2 Layer 2   Layer 2 Layer 2Layer 2 Layer 2   Layer 2 Layer 2   Layer 2 Layer 2Layer 2 Layer 2   Layer 2 Layer 2   Layer 2 Layer 2Layer 2 Layer 2   Layer 2 Layer 2   Layer 2 Layer 2vLayer 2 Layer 2   Layer 2 Layer 2   Layer 2 Layer 2vvvLayer 2 Layer 2   Layer 2 Layer 2   Layer 2 Layer 2Layer 2 Layer 2   Layer 2 Layer 2   Layer 2 Layer 2Layer 2 Layer 2   Layer 2 Layer 2   Layer 2 Layer 2
  </div>
      <div class="absolute2">
      top 2
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```